# Powershell script to find a folder and copy to another folder

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a long directory path. The nested folder values keep changing as per project name. but last directory PackageTmp does not change, Looking forward to copy files from PackageTmp to another directory. I want to copy all subfolder and files from C:\unzip\Content\D_C\a\1\s\src\prj\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp to C:\deploy. My code is copying to C:\deploy\PackageTmp.

```
Source Dir :- C:\unzip\Content\D_C\a\1\s\src\prj\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp
Inconsistent Path :- \D_C\a\1\s\src\prj\obj\Release\Package\
Target Dir :- C:\deploy\
Non working code :- Get-ChildItem C:\unzip\ -Filter PackageTmp -Recurse | where {($_.psiscontainer)}| Copy-Item -Destination C:\deploy\ -Recurse -filter * -Force
```

Comment: There's a space in your `destination` parameter.

Comment: You updated it with unnecessary parameters now. What isn't working by the way? Does it not copy? You can specify the `-Directory` if you're looking for just the folder and are using posh v3.

Comment: I was working and got it copying to folder C:\deploy\PackageTmp,found it on another stack overflow question.Thanks. Looking if can copy to C:\deploy\ somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Analysis

Looks like you're almost there.  Your script is just finding the `PackageTmp` directory and then passing it down the pipeline where it's eventually copied to the destination, directory and contents all included. The trick is, once you find the `PackageTmp` directory, you then can use a wildcard to get everything that's IN the `PackageTmp` directory and copy that to your destination.

### Code

I tweaked your non-working code, so hopefully this works for you.

```powershell
# Get the PackageTmp directory
$PackageTmp = Get-ChildItem C:\unzip\ -Filter PackageTmp -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.psiscontainer)}

# Print the FullName of the PackageTmp directory
Write-Host "PackageTmp: $($PackageTmp.FullName)"

# Recursively copy everything in the PackageTmp directory to our destination directory
Copy-Item -Path "$($PackageTmp.FullName)\*" -Destination C:\deploy\ -Recurse -filter * -Force
```

### Explanation

I store the `PackageTmp` location in a variable.  I can then specify that I want to copy everything INSIDE the `PackageTmp` directory by using the `-Path "$($PackageTmp.FullName)\*"` parameter, note the use of the wildcard `\*`.  This doesn't copy the `PackageTmp` directory, like you requested.

So effectively instead of doing this:

```
Copy C:\unzip\Content\D_C\a\1\s\src\prj\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp -> C:\deploy\
```

We're just doing this:

```
Copy C:\unzip\Content\D_C\a\1\s\src\prj\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\* to C:\deploy\
```

Comment: Cool, Thanks a lot, is it possible to print value of Get-ChildItem, Like path of PackageTmp,

Comment: @AshishMishra Sure, you can store the contents of `Get-ChildItem` in a variable, print the `FullName` of the variable and then use that variable in a separate copy command.  Breaking up the command makes it easier to understand too. - I'll edit my answer to include this.